# Adding ordinal suffix to a name to make the record unique

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Right now when file already exist I added prefix which is a timestamp to the filename to make it unique.

But instead of using timestamp I want to use ordinal suffix. How do we implement or add an ordinal suffix to the filename ? For example there is an existing file in the databse with a filename HELLOWORLD. Then I add again a file with a filename HELLOWORLD since it already exist the new filename now would be HELLOWORLD-1st. If I add a file again with filename HELLOWORLD it would check for the updates of the file and the latest is HELLOWORLD-1st so the new filename now would be HELLOWORLD-2nd since HELLOWORLD and HELLOWORLD-1st already exist. any idea how we can implement something like this ? Thank you.

#Code to check if record exists

```
const file = await context.service.Model.findOne({
    where: { humanId: record.id, filename: data.filename },
    paranoid: false,
  });

if (file) {
    const prefix = Date.now().toString();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const fileParts = data.filename.split('.');
    filename = `${fileParts[0]}-${prefix}.${fileParts[1]}`;
  }
```

#ordinal suffix function

```
function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
}
```

Comment: This is going to be a bit tricky because it looks like you want a unique suffix for each distinct filename. You also haven't told us whether filenames can be deleted, e.g. if you start with `HELLO-1st`, `HELLO-2nd` and `HELLO-3rd`, then delete `HELLO-2nd`, would you want the next filename to be `HELLO-2nd` or `HELLO-4th`? When you grow to lots of dupes, determining the next "free" filename may take a fair amount of time. At the end of the day, your scheme is probably not worth writing. I would stick with using a timestamp, probably in conjunction with the process ID to make it truly unique.

Comment: How about adding an increment number to a filename @kmoser ? would that be a good idea ? what is the other way too ensure it is unique aside from using timestamp ? cause timestamp is too long to add on a filename like 1596010248422.

Comment: also sir the file is not hard deleted so even the file is delete it is just soft deleted so it still exist on the databse.

Comment: This is going to be a bit tricky because it looks like you want a unique suffix for each distinct filename. NO. I will only add a suffix to a filename if that filename has duplicates on the database

Comment: Yes, obviously just for the files that were deleted. That doesn't change the fact that it requires you to distinguish between multiple filenames. You're saying a timestamp is "too long to add on a filename" but you don't say why. Are filenames limited in length?

Comment: what I mean its too long for example. HELLOWORLD-15356543633 , it is not a good idea to display it on the list with the long name.

Comment: @kmoser so do you mean its impossible to implement using ordinal?

Comment: Ordinal is one choice to avoid same name in file system. Many programs do this like Browsers. What you should do is just add a while loop to try filenames until somewhere is empry.

Comment: @yao99 can you provide or atleast post an answer example Sir ?

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin It's not impossible. It just becomes computationally inefficient when you have lots of duplicates. See my answer for one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly loop until you find a `filename` that does not exist in the DB:

```js
let basename = filename = data.filename
let suffix = 0

while (true) {
  const file = await context.service.Model.findOne({
    where: { humanId: record.id, filename: filename },
    paranoid: false,
  })

  if ( ! file ) {
    break; // filename does not exist in DB, so exit loop
  }

  let ordinal_suffix = ordinal_suffix_of( ++suffix )
  filename = `${basename}-${ordinal_suffix}`
}

// filename is now guaranteed to be unique
```

If `filename` exists in the DB, it appends the ordinal suffix you wanted (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.) and keeps looking until it doesn't find a file in the DB with that name.

Comment: this is not about file systems Sir , this is just about a record of files in the database. please check my db query above.

Comment: You should be able to easily adapt this to search the database instead of the filesystem.

Comment: can you modify it sir based on my sample query above ?